# akka: using akka-typed to implement the active objects pattern

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

The Akka [Typed Actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/typed-actors.html) documentation states that it will be superseded by [Akka Typed](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/typed.html#typed-scala). I am inferring from this that Akka Typed can be used to implement the [Active Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object); but it is not too clear to me how. Here is my attempt so far; I'm aware it stinks :D

```
object HelloWorld {
  final case class Greet(whom: String, replyTo: ActorRef[Greeted])
  final case class Greeted(whom: String)

  private val greeter = Static[Greet] { msg ⇒
    println(s"Hello ${msg.whom}!")
    msg.replyTo ! Greeted(msg.whom)
  }

  private val system = ActorSystem("HelloWorld", Props(greeter))

  def greet(whom: String): Future[Greeted] = system ? (Greet(whom, _))
}
```

Cheers

Comment: P.S. could someone with sufficient rep create a tag for `akka-typed`?

Comment: Regarding the tag: done (tag description pending approval). Regarding the question: what have you tried?

Comment: I have edited my question to include what I have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Active Object Pattern as defined by the page you link to is not desirable for all the reasons why TypedActors are being removed: the fact that a method is executed asynchronously is so important that it should not be hidden by technologies like proxy objects that implement normal interfaces. Instead, Akka Typed allows you to write nearly the same code as if it was an Active Object while retaining the asynchronous marker: instead of selecting a method with the `.` syntax you send a message using `?` (or `!` if the protocol is not simple request–response). Your example would look like this:

```
object HelloWorld {
  final case class Greet(whom: String)(replyTo: ActorRef[Greeted])
  final case class Greeted(whom: String)

  val greeter = Static[Greet] { msg ⇒
    println(s"Hello ${msg.whom}!")
    msg.replyTo ! Greeted(msg.whom)
  }
}

object Sample extends App {
  import HelloWorld._
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloWorld", Props(greeter))
  val fg = system ? Greet("John")
}
```

Please note that creating a separate thread (or ActorSystem) per object may sound okay as per the classical pattern, but doing that foregoes many of the benefits of a message-driven architecture, namely that many Actors can share the same  resources for more efficient execution and they can form supervision hierarchies for principled failure handling etc.